# Ctrl+0 for my own default zoom level for IE?

Tags: internet-explorer

I would like to assign Ctrl+0 to my own default zoom level in Internet Explorer 11. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

It is a registry change you have to make - [Source](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/change-zoom-level-in-internet-explorer)

1. Open Registry Editor - regedit32.exe
2. Go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Zoom`
3. Double click on `ZoomFactor` in the right hand pane
4. Entered your desired zoom percentage followed by three 0's (125% would be 125000)

Comment: I had tried this idea before. This only change the default zoom but it doesn't cause Ctrl+0 to be assigned to your new default zoom factor.